# Is it possible to read from mount point if original file is locked?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to read files from mount point, but the problem is that original files are locked by some other process, so when I try to get handle to the file via

```
  hFile = CreateFile (szPath,
         GENERIC_READ | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY | READ_CONTROL,
         FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
         NULL,
         OPEN_EXISTING,
         FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT,
         NULL);
```

I got `32 - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` error. 
I use following code to determine whether path is a mount point

```
BOOL bResult = FALSE;
dwAttribut = GetFileAttributes(pwszPath);

if ((FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & dwAttribut) &&
        (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT & dwAttribut))
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    memset(&FindFileData, 0, sizeof(FindFileData));
    hFind = FindFirstFileW(pwszPath, &FindFileData);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
         if (FindFileData.dwReserved0 & IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT)
         {
             bResult =  TRUE;
         }
    }
}
```

And it works ok for the root mount point folder(`e.g. C:/mount/G`), but when I test with it some nested path(`e.g. C:/mount/G/test`) it says that this path is not a mount folder.
So is it possible to read a file from the mount folder and avoid problem with another file is being used by another process ? Because I've been playing around the problem and it seems like only the root folder is treated as a mount point and all nested items could be read only from original location...

When I check this file via ProcessExplorer through a mount point it says that no one is using it.

Comment: Just because `G` is a reparse point doesn't imply that everything under it is. If you want to open a file underneath a reparse point just open it as normal. The whole point of reparse points is they're handled transparently by the file system.

Comment: Mount points have nothing to do with file sharing.  You can't bypass sharing restrictions this way.  (You can, however, use VSS to create a volume shadow copy and read from that.)

Comment: Do you mean VSS like from \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood the concept: **mount point**.

> *... it seems like only the root folder is treated as a mount point and all nested items could ...*

The root folder is **the** mount point, all other nested files and folders are relative to the mount point.

If the root mount point is folder `C:/mount/G` then folder `C:/mount/G/test` is inside or is relative to mount point, hence **is not a mount folder**.

The mount folder here is `C:/mount/G`.

**About your other question.**

> So is it possible to read a file from the mount folder and avoid problem with another file is being used by another process?

I don't think so. The fact you mount a directory tree don't duplicate files inside the mounted dir. So if a file is being accessed in the "original" directory it will be in the mounted tree as well.

You have guessed right: *...all nested items could be read only from original location...*

Comment: And what about Linux, does it work the same for Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

`FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` is only needed if you want to open the actual reparse point (`C:\mount\G`; eg the data that actually tells the OS that a reparse is happening). For example, you would use that flag to determine where the `C:\mount\G` actually points to. If you don't want to do that *and the path you selected is not a reparse point* then your mileage may vary.

As far as what happens if another process is reading the file... well that's all up to whatever sharing flags the other process provided and of course your own sharing flags. If the other process didn't provide `FILE_SHARE_READ` permission, then generally no you cannot read the file while the other process does not let you.